# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

Please help me.
I am new in React and try to build an application to add contact in Local storage and delete contact. Following are the code of my App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {uuid} from 'uuidv4'
import AddContact from './AddContact'
import ContactList from './ContactList'
import Header from './Header'

function App() {
  //useState Hooks in React
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'contacts'
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contacts)
    setContacts([...contacts, {id: uuid(), ...contact}])
  }

  const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id
    })
    setContacts(newContactList)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieve_contact = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    if (retrieve_contact) {
      setContacts(retrieve_contact)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
  }, [contacts])

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I got the error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Please help me how can i remove this error.
Thank you!

Comment: Please log `retrieve_contact`. I;d willing to bet that `retrieve_contact` is always true value

Comment: @captain-yossarian even if that is true, there is no reason why it should result in an infinite loop. That useEffect hook is only going to execute once.

Comment: @BenWainwright you are right

Comment: The problem i am facing in this line                                                                                               ` setContacts([...contacts, { id: uuid(), ...contact }]);`  id:uuid()  when i remove id: uuid() then i got the same key for each element

Comment: when exactly does it say it? after you click something or right away? it looks like more code and explanation will help to understand the problem more easily

Answer (score 1):

You are updating react state inside `useEffect`, which triggers an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
  }, [contacts])
```

In short, you told `useEffect` to run when there are changes to `contacts` (by passing them into the dependency array as the second param to `useEffect`), causing it to run every time `contacts` changes, which triggers a state change to `contacts`, which triggers the `useEffect` loop again, infinitely. If the array was empty, it would run once on start.

For what you are trying to do here, it makes more sense to update your store when you add or remove contacts, i.e. call the storage functions from within your event handlers.

Here's a working [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-curie-ferpm4?file=/src/App.js) with the code you provided.

Comment: I dont quite follow your solution. Everytime contacts changes, the useEffect will fire. Shouldn't that only result in storing an item in local Storage? Why would the call to localStorage trigger a state change for contacts?

Comment: @MarkM I think you're right! I tried to get the sandbox to reproduce the error again, and was not able to sort it out. However, that maximum call exceeded is usually a result of updating state from inside useEffect. It could be happening elsewhere in the stack